# Sqoop job get Stuck when import data from Oracle to Hive

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

So I was trying to import a table from Oracle to Hive, using Sqoop. Here is my query

```
sqoop-import --hive-import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.35.10.180:1521:dms 
--table DEFECT 
--hive-database inspex 
--username INSPEX 
--password inspex
```

Yarn seems to split the job into 4 parts.

```
17/02/17 15:15:17 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.9.1
17/02/17 15:15:17 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/02/17 15:15:17 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
17/02/17 15:15:17 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
17/02/17 15:15:18 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
17/02/17 15:15:18 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
17/02/17 15:15:18 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/02/17 15:15:18 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
17/02/17 15:15:18 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM "DEFECT" t WHERE 1=0
17/02/17 15:15:18 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/72422bf2a67c745893ae440ad77e3049/DEFECT.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
17/02/17 15:15:20 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/72422bf2a67c745893ae440ad77e3049/DEFECT.jar
17/02/17 15:15:20 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
17/02/17 15:15:20 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
17/02/17 15:15:20 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of DEFECT
17/02/17 15:15:20 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
17/02/17 15:15:20 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
17/02/17 15:15:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
17/02/17 15:15:21 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at vn1.localdomain/10.35.10.17:8032
17/02/17 15:15:23 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
17/02/17 15:15:23 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN("DEFECT_INDEX"), MAX("DEFECT_INDEX") FROM "DEFECT"
17/02/17 15:15:45 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:4
17/02/17 15:15:45 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1487360998088_0003
17/02/17 15:15:45 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1487360998088_0003
17/02/17 15:15:45 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://vn1.localdomain:8088/proxy/application_1487360998088_0003/
17/02/17 15:15:45 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1487360998088_0003
17/02/17 15:15:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1487360998088_0003 running in uber mode : false
17/02/17 15:15:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/02/17 15:15:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
17/02/17 15:16:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 75% reduce 0%
```

Then it got stuck in 75% and runs forever. I notice that 3 out of 4 jobs are finished pretty quick. Except for one:
[image]

Seems like this job isn't making any progress and just stay at 0%. I checked out the syslog:

```
2017-02-17 15:15:53,795 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2017-02-17 15:15:53,851 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2017-02-17 15:15:53,851 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system started
2017-02-17 15:15:53,859 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Executing with tokens:
2017-02-17 15:15:53,859 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1487360998088_0003, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@41480ec1)
2017-02-17 15:15:53,948 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying again. Got null now.
2017-02-17 15:15:54,426 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: mapreduce.cluster.local.dir for child: /yarn/nm/usercache/root/appcache/application_1487360998088_0003
2017-02-17 15:15:55,409 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2017-02-17 15:15:55,813 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2017-02-17 15:15:55,822 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2017-02-17 15:15:56,278 INFO [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
2017-02-17 15:15:56,411 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: "DEFECT_INDEX" >= 1 AND "DEFECT_INDEX" < 545225318
2017-02-17 15:15:56,491 INFO [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.OracleDBRecordReader: Time zone has been set to GMT
2017-02-17 15:15:56,564 INFO [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader: Working on split: "DEFECT_INDEX" >= 1 AND "DEFECT_INDEX" < 545225318
2017-02-17 15:15:56,610 INFO [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader: Executing query: SELECT "DEFECT_INDEX", "LAYER_SCAN_INDEX", "DEFECT_SITE_ID", "CLUSTER_ID", "CARRY_OVER", "VERIFIED_ADDER", "REPEATING_DEFECT", "TEST_NUMBER", "X_DIE_COORDINATE", "Y_DIE_COORDINATE", "X_COORDINATE", "Y_COORDINATE", "X_DEFECT_SIZE", "Y_DEFECT_SIZE", "D_SIZE", "INSPECT_INTENSITY", "PATTERN_ID", "SURFACE", "ANGLE", "HOT_SPOT", "ASPECT_RATIO", "GRAY_SCALE", "MACROSIGID", "REGIONID", "SEMREVSAMPLE", "POLARITY", "DBGROUP", "CAREAREAGROUPCODE", "VENNID", "SEGMENTID", "MDAT_OFFSET", "DESIGNFILEFLOORPLANID", "DBSCRITICALITYINDEX", "CELLSIZE", "PCI", "LINECOMPLEXITY", "DCIRANGE", "GDSX", "GDSY" FROM "DEFECT" WHERE ( "DEFECT_INDEX" >= 1 ) AND ( "DEFECT_INDEX" < 545225318 )
```

The log ends on starting executing query. I wait for like 10 hours and still there's no update. Which shouldn't be right because it's not really that big.

I didn't find any error in the log. Before this I have successfully imported several tables from oracle to hive. So I think my configuration is fine.

I have tried to set mapper from 1 to 100 and still didn't work. And I notice that the task which PK starts from 1~somenumber always show 0% progress while other works just fine.

I'm looking for any suggestions or help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jesse, did you make sure that you are "keeping the connection alive" from Oracle?

Comment: Hi @dbustosp What do you mean 'keep the connection alive'? My database and cluster have a stable connection if that's what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

by default, sqoop aplit your job in 4 mappers based on the PK of your table, however depending on the distribution of your data, this can be very inefficient. You didnt talk about the size of your cluster or your data but I would sugeest see how is the distribution of your data and try set a greater number of maps(-m option)  using a different column to split the load (split-by option).  your job is using the defect_index column to split the work

Comment: This is definitely not an answer. That's why we have comments over question.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried to set mapper from 1 to 100 and still didn't work. And I notice that the task which PK starts from 1~somenumber always show 0% progress while other works just fine.

Comment: This is probably because the distribution in your data. Could you share your table columns?

Comment: Hi @lake. I notice that if I skip the part which PK starts from 1 to 53291. I can import the data. But in Hive table PK is null. Here is my table screenshot in Oracle. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4zBU9nhCbhYa3hHS3BLVkhNRzQ). DEFECT_INDEX is PK. Any thoughts?

Comment: i would suggest run the same query that sqoop runs to calculate the splits for each column and determinate how is the distribution in your data. You have to choose a column considering distribute the data in the mapper in similar amounts, also, i would be better if the column is indexed